# Program skips NSURLRequest used to download txt file, if placed in IB action with other code

Tags: ios, objective-c, curl, nsurl

I am using a NSURL request in objective -c in order to download a webpage and place it in a text file. This is similar to the curl function used in UNIX.

Here is the code:

```
    NSString *documentDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
    NSString *filePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.txt"];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=JNJ"]];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
               NSLog(@"Download Error:%@",error.description);
        }
        if (data) {
            [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
            NSLog(@"File is saved to %@",filePath);
        }
    }];
```

I am finding that if I execute the code in its own IB action (no other code) linked to a test button it is working with no bugs.

However in the main IB action the program compiler seems to be skipping over the code and not executing it (observed with lack of downloaded file). I would appreciate feedback on the possible sources of this bug.
Thanks

Comment: Put in some breakpoints and examine if they are hit and if so the results. The compiler, etc does not skip over code, it executes exactly the code you write.

Comment: Oddly enough it is hitting all the breakpoints even the NSURLConnection. However it is not entering either of the if statements. I added an else and it did not enter that as well. I think this means that it is executing the  NSURLConnection however not downloading the file. What could be causing that?

Comment: Check the NSUrlResponse object to see if you're getting a HTTP Error Code

Comment: When I try to print the NSUrlResponse or assign it to a variable in order to check the error code Xcode is saying that the variable is an undeclared identifier. Is this the incorrect method of checking the error code?

Comment: Will do, however I need more reputation before i can vote up,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create a `NSOperationQueue` instance:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request [NSOperationQueue new] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
```